# How to input a symbolic variable in SymbolicC++

Tags: c++, symbolic-computation, symbolicc++

I'm making a program that takes input for an expression and integrates it and prints the result to the user. I'm using SymbolicC++, but can't seem to figure out how to input a symbolic... how do I do this - I'm using Visual Studio for my IDE

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Like this (example from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SymbolicC++)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "symbolicc++.h"
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    Symbolic x("x");
    cout << integrate(x+1, x);     // => 1/2*x^(2)+x
    Symbolic y("y");
    cout << df(y, x);              // => 0
    cout << df(y[x], x);           // => df(y[x],x)
    cout << df(exp(cos(y[x])), x); // => -sin(y[x])*df(y[x],x)*e^cos(y[x])
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I saw that example... my problem is not with the actual integration, but taking input for the expression to be inputted... cin and getline don't seem to work

Comment: @Rahul You want user to input `"x"` and `"y"`?

Comment: No he should input the expression... for example he should input x*x and he would get back x*x*x/3 (in case of integration)